# How to use np.transpose()

Tags: python, numpy, transpose, scikit-image

I am trying to understand how to use np.transpose() properly.

I have a np array of shape `(4,28,28,8,8)`. So this is 4 images of shape `(224,224)` that I viewed as shown by the previous shape.

I would like to revert back to `(4,224,224)`. I feel the best way to go about is to use np.transpose() and reshape() functions. But I am hitting a roadblock as to how to revert back correctly.

Help. Please and thank you.

EDIT: (4,224,224) is 4 (this variable is subject to change as the number of images I load can change it can be 4, it can be 1000) images of shape (224,224). I used listdir() to load images. While loading I resized to the current shape of (224,224). I am going to perform operations on the shape (4,28,28,8,8) which is technically, 4 images, of shape (224,224) broken into (28,28) blocks, each containing (8,8) blocks. This shape I got by using view_as_blocks provided by scikit-image. Once I perform the operations which require that shape, I must revert back to (4,224,224). Where I am stuck.

Comment: How did you get to `(4,28,28,8,8)`?

Comment: What is the meaning of each dimension in `(4,28,28,8,8)`? This affects the answer.

Comment: Do you want to reshape from (4,28,8,28,8)? Transpose parameter 
 `(0,1,3,2,4)` should work.

Comment: @JeremyMcGibbon I have edited the question with an explanation of how I got the shape and why I need to revert back.

Comment: How's this different from your Aug 22 question?  It was marked a duplicate, with a transpose answer, https://stackoverflow.com/q/41510395/901925

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is probably :

```
b=np.swapaxes(a,3,2).reshape(4,28*8,28*8)
```

a beeing your array.

Comment: So there is no use of using transpose at all?

Comment: @JeremyMcGibbon Can you please suggest a way I can convert (4, 28, 28, 8, 8) to (4, 224, 224)? Or how to access the inner blocks?

Comment: This solution looks like it should work. `swapaxes` does the job of `transpose` here.

Comment: `transpose`is  good for 2 dimensions; for more dimensions, it reverses all the dimensions. `swapaxes` is more clear in your case, but you can also use  `transpose(a,(0,1,3,2,4))`.

Comment: @B.M. I used transpose in the end but this worked too. Thank you.